# Why can't Tomcat/JSP see these classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to write a web app using JSP and Java on a Tomcat 7.0.14, and part of it involves connecting with a MySQL server using [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).

Here's a basic view of my directory structure:

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.14
|- webapps
   |- ROOT
     |- WEB-INF
     |   |- classes
     |   |   |- some-package-path
     |   |      \- foo.java
     |   |      \- foo.class
     |   |- lib
     |      \- hibernate3.jar
     \- file_giving_issues.jsp
```

Now, "file_giving_issues.jsp", as you might have guessed, is the file giving me issues. It can't see the classes contained in the various hibernate jar files. I used the following statement:

```
<%@ page import="org.hibernate.Session" %>
```

Here, Tomcat tells me,

```
Only a type can be imported. org.hibernate.Session resolves to a package.
```

This, by the way, is not true; Session is definitely a type, not a package, and it's in that `hibernate3.jar`. More specifically, it exists here:

```
WEB-INF/lib/hibernate3.jar/org/hibernate/Session.class
```

But I figured I'd play ball and just import everything from org.hibernate, like so:

```
<%@ page import="org.hibernate.*" %>
```

Even more bafflingly, Tomcat now tells me,

```
Session cannot be resolved to a type.
```

So, I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the way Tomcat is configured, or with my class directory structures, or if I don't understans the way JARs work, or what. From what I understand, the JAR files in WEB-INF/lib should always be on Tomcat's Classpath, and those files in WEB-INF/classes/some-package-path work fine, so I'm lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to represent your file_giving_issues.jsp in the ROOT app directory instead of in the webapps directory?

Comment: Note: that was a problem with the question, not with the structure itself. That is, the problem still remains.

Comment: I figured that was the case. Don't have an immediate answer, but wanted to rule out "but it's not in that webapp"!

Comment: Is it just Hibernate jars?  Do you get the same error trying to import classes from any other jars in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Sorry, took a few minutes to throw to get a test class, jar it up, move it around, and test it against another jsp file. Same result as with the Hibernate jars.

Comment: not directly related but using the hibernate classes directly in a JSP is a bad practice most of the time ...

Comment: Rights? Also, tried putting everything in a nonroot context?

Comment: @Jarrod, yeah, I know, I don't plan to keep it this way. I'm trying for a bit of a proof of concept, both for the use of Hibernate and to make sure my Tomcat server is set up properly.

Comment: @MJB, I definitely have rights to the server and all subfolders. As I mentioned, I can do whatever I want with straight JSP or with any classes located in the WEB-INF/classes subdirectory, so the fact that it's in the ROOT project shouldn't actually matter.

Comment: you might try using something more proven like Tomcat 6.x and see if it might be a bug in 7. Personally I avoid the newest versions until they have a few point releases under their belts and lots of support from the internet in general.

Comment: @KenB - well I was playing with Tomcat 7.0.14 about 3 weeks ago, and tested our app (which uses hibernate) and it worked fine. Differences? a) ran under Windows as admin (hence my rights question) b) ran as context /RetainServer c) the context file was explicitly deployed to conf/Catalina/localHost/RetainServer.xml, and the app itself was elsewhere on the C drive. I wouldn't have thought c) relevant, hence my mention of a) and b). If you are running linux, humor me and quickly run tomcat as root just for the heck of it to check rights?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have root access on this server. Anyway, I ultimately solved the problem by moving the JARs to `apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib`, which is the common lib directory for all web-apps. I don't like this solution, as it is not appropriate for all JAR files, but technically Hibernate should probably be there anyway, since it is likely going to be used by another web-app in the future anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Only a type can be imported. XXXXX resolves to a package.
```

The above usually means that the container is not able to find the class file.

Can you see whether you are able to import other jars or classes? I mean, to debug; create a simple hello world JSP and import some of your custom classes and see whether you can work with it.

Also, confirm that the Session class is indeed there in one of the jars in your lib directory.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can import anything I want from `WEB-INF/classes`. It's only the JARs in the `lib` directory I can't reach. And yeah, Session is definitely where it's supposed to be in the appropriate jar. It's located here: 
`WEB-INF/lib/hibernate3.jar/org/hibernate/Session.class'. I should probably add this above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other JARs in WEB-INF/lib, except hibernate?
I had a similar problem: tomcat didn't see JARs in WEB-INF/lib, but worked fine with the same files in the global lib directory.

In my case, I removed some unused legacy files from WEB-INF/lib, and it suddenly started working.
It seems, tomcat won't load some files from WEB-INF/lib (for instance, it complains about any file with javax.servlet classes), and will silently ignore others.